# Expresso-store select modifiers by name

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

I want to select modifiers by name because for my modifier's it's not possible to put all modifier_options in the same output, for example a `<select>` form. So how would I be able to select a specific modifier?

Or do I need to walk through all modifiers and doe this with something like this:

```
{modifiers}
  {if "{modifier_name}" == "myMatch"}
  // Specific HTML for this match
  {if:else "{modifier_name}" == "myOtherMatch"}
  // Specific HTML for this other match
  {/if}
{/modifiers}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `{modifiers}` tag is a loop so within that loop if you wanted to call out a particular modifier by name then you'd need to run a conditional check as you are currently showing in your example.

Comment: This is as I already wrote. The problem is that I'm also using translations so the `{modifier_name}` is not in my control.. BTW: I need the quotation marks around `{modifier_name}`.

Comment: What kind of translations? You make no mention of this in your question. Stepping back a little however what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want more fined-grained control over your modifiers you do have the option of [text input modifiers](https://exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#input_custom_modifier_name_name). If you also view the source of your template with the modifiers loop applied you'll see the output and can hard code the same name attributes and values if required. All depends on what you're trying to do.